# Exclude Directory-Pattern in gulp with glob in `gulp.src`

Tags: path, gulp, glob

I am trying to glob all files&directories with `gulp.src()` expcept all directories starting with the character `_` (i.e. `_Stuff/`). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say you have a folder `project/src` that contains the following files:

```
file.txt
folder
folder/file.txt
folder/_subfolder
folder/_subfolder/file.txt
folder/subfolder
folder/subfolder/file.txt
_folder
_folder/file.txt
_folder/_subfolder
_folder/_subfolder/file.txt
_folder/subfolder
_folder/subfolder/file.txt
```

Then this task in `project/Gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src([
      'src/**/*',         //select all files
      '!src/**/_*/',      //exclude folders starting with '_'
      '!src/**/_*/**/*',  //exclude files/subfolders in folders starting with '_'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Will result in the following files being written to `project/dist`:

```
file.txt
folder
folder/file.txt
folder/subfolder
folder/subfolder/file.txt
```